# Incorrect symbol appears under math environment

Tags: math-mode, symbols, brackets, missing

When I write under math environment, e.g. $y(t)$, the brackets doesn't show. Also, I found, when I $\sum a_n$, or $\int_t$, it comes up with flowery "P" and "R" respectively. I have listed all the packages I used for my file. Are there any packages not working with math environment? Or what cause such problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{MnSymbol}%
\usepackage{wasysym}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=WaymoBlue]{hyperref} %for hyperlinks, and set the color of the links
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} % privides the H option of \begin{figure}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % produces random text for testing
\begin{document}
$y(t)$ $\sum a_n$ or $\int_t$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Since the preamble features the instruction `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, there is absolutely no benefit to loading `xcolor` and `colortbl` separately once more. While on the topic of needlessly loading packages more than once: Don't load `array` twice unless you like code clutter.

Comment: Incidentally, I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot of the problem behavior you've encountered. Feel free to revert.

Comment: The strange-looking math-mode output appears to be caused by some unfortunate interaction of the `MnSymbol` and `pslatex` packages (a) with each other and possibly (b) with one or more of the other font packages you load. I suggest you cease loading both `MnSymbol` and `pslatex` and see if your document compiles satisfactorily. If that's the case, you can safely strike both packages from your document's preamble.

Comment: why are you loading so many conflicting font packages?  (there is no reason to use `pslatex`, I wrote it but haven't used it since last century) but tgbonum and MnSymbol  and mathptmx and .wasysym and ... which fonts do you want to use?

Comment: Thank you so much! I removed packages xcolor, colortbl, MnSymbol (after remove this one, problem solved), pslatex and replicated array. I would like to keep least packages. It is added over time through problem solving, and I didn't do much study about packages. I will start from now on.

Answer (score 1):

As per `David Carlisle` comment, really you need this much of packages? Also, note that you should use either `MnSymbol` or `mathptmx` (it is not advisable to use the package `mathptmx`, switch over to `newtxmath`), don't combine both. Many packages are repeated in your code, I've modified some of your code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}%
\usepackage{wasysym}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=WaymoBlue]{hyperref} %for hyperlinks, and set the color of the links
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{contour}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} % privides the H option of \begin{figure}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % produces random text for testing
\begin{document}
$y(t)$ $[\sum a_n]$ or $\int_t$
\end{document}
```

You need to decide what are the `packages` you going to use...